# jQuery AJAX type: 'GET' make problems with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I tried until this morning to retreive data from Mysql and ajax.

This is my code :

HTML :

```
$.ajax({
   //type:'GET',
   url: "/lecture_message_pilote.php",
   data: ({location_id:zlid}),
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: 'json',                //data format
   success: function(data)          //on recieve of reply
   {
       var zidpilote = data[0];              //get id
       var zmessage = data[1];           //get name
       alert(zmessage);
   }
});
```

And PHP :

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from Test_phoneGAP_message where IDPILOTE = '".$location_id."'");
$array = mysql_fetch_row($result);  
echo (json_encode($array));

mysql_close();
```

I've the error message : UNDEFINED for alert(zmessage);
If I use the PHP request :

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from Test_phoneGAP_message");
```

I have a good result. I think my PHP don't take the `$location_id`.

Comment: [**The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and will be removed in future PHP versions.**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) Use `mysqli` or PDO instead.

Answer (score 0):

try to access the parameter via the $_REQUEST["location_id"] element of php.

i.e.

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from Test_phoneGAP_message where IDPILOTE = '".$_REQUEST["location_id"]."'"); $array = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

Comment: It's good idea to not use `$_REQUEST` and use `$_GET` or `$_POST` in cases.

Comment: @user2078935 If it works, then you must accept it as the answer.